# How to limit selection to maximum two cells in a row of a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I am currently trying to limit selection of maximum two consecutive cells in a single row of a DataGrid in WPF. How can I do that? Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about what you are trying to do? There might be an alternative to using a DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to listen to `SelectionChanged` and then manipulate the `SelectedItems` property manually.